# How do I upload music files to my android phone?

Tags: file-transfer, downloading

I have bought some music on my phone. I can't find the files on my phone. I have found them on my computer. I created a playlist on my computer but not on my phone. I had found a conversation about how to do this, but when I joined this group I lost the link. I had tried to do some of the things that were mentioned in the conversation, none of them worked or the settings they mentioned weren't where they said they would be. How do I get music on my phone?

Comment: How did you buy music for your phone? Through an app or music placed in your SD card. Also from the computer, what is your music encoded like. Is it mp3, wav...

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you seen our [file-transfer tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-transfer/info) yet? Contains several links which sound suitable. Also check our [other file-transfer questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer). I'd wonder if this wasn't already answered in the past multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If the music you bought are in mp3 format and are on your computer:

1. *Plug your phone into your computer*
2. *Open the music folder*
3. *Copy your mp3 music files that are on your computer*
4. *Paste the mp3 music files into the music folder*
5. *Enjoy your music!*

If the music was bought through the Google Playstore or Google Play Music:

1. *Open Google Play Music*
2. *Find the album or single*
3. *Tap on the diagonally pointing arrow head*
4. *Check the box to "Keep on Device"*
5. *The music should download*